# How to compare content of xhtml and pdf file?

Tags: php, linux, pdf, xhtml, compare

Latex file is the source, from which pdf and xhtml file will be created. Now I need to compare the content of both pdf and xhtml file. Just to make sure whether the PDF file contents exist in xhtml file too. how to do it?

If we want to compare two pdf files, we can use `diffpdf` , `pdftk` etc. But how about comparing content between xhtml and pdf? Or Is there any alternative way to do it?

**Additional Note:**

OS-linux

Language known-PHP

Comment: you can convert `xhtml to pdf` and than compare both PDFs.. http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/